# If I want to run two parallel AsyncTask do I have to use executeOnExecutor on both calls?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to run two `AsyncTask` at the same time. I know I should use `executeOnExecutor` to achive that but my question is do I have to call `executeOnExecutor` on both calls or only one of them? and does the ordering matters?

For example

```
Task1.executeOnExecutor()
Task2.executeOnExecutor()
```

or

```
Task1.executeOnExecutor()
Task2.execute()
```

Comment: Please try all possibilities and then report.

Comment: @blackapps I tried both it's working fine , But I don't know if there anything that might happen in the long run. Maybe there are things I'm not aware of. Thank you